# Vaadin Binding API and Ids

Tags: java, vaadin

I am currently working with Vaadin 10 and the Vaadin binding API. Basically I am wondering what I have to do to preserve the ids of my objects. Let's assume I have a domain object representing an entity in the database. Once loaded or created it has an id.

```
public class Person {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  // ...
}
```

In my view I have a field to edit the name and a binder for my domain object.

```
...
final TextField name = new TextField();
personBinder.bind(name, "name");
...
```

Now what do I do about the id? If I save and load the bean (`readBean`/`writeBean`), the id just disappears. However, of course I don't want to show the id in my view. Do I need to store it in a new attribute of my view class? Or is there a trick to preserve such attributes in the binder? I seem to be able to retrieve the bean with the id if I use `setBean`/`getBean` instead, but that does not seem to be right...

Thank you very much and best regards!

Edit 1:

Assume I have following code

```
TextField name = new TextField();
personBinder.bind(name, "name");
add(name);

Button button = new Button("Save", e -> {
    Person p = new Person();
    personBinder.writeBeanIfValid(p);
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getId());
});
add(button);

Person p = new Person();
p.setName("John");
p.setId("42");

personBinder.readBean(p);
```

The id, as it is not bound to any field, is not preserved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say that the id disappears. Isn't it so that the id of the instance you pass to `writeBean` is preserved?

Comment: Another question: You write that using `setBean`/`getBean` doesn't seem right. What's that based on?

Comment: Hello, please take a look at the first edit of my post. I don't want to use setBean/getBean as from the looks of it, the readBean/writeBean method perform additional actions.

Comment: The "problem" is that you're passing a newly created instance to `writeBeanIfValid`. The intended way of using it is that you either pass it the original bean instance, or alternatively explicitly fetch a new copy from the database (which would thus then have the id already populated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the setBean/getBean approach is actually not wrong. At least the Vaadin 8 documentation has an example where this is used. It is listed under "Automatic Saving". My example code from above should therefore probably be something like this:

```
TextField name = new TextField();
personBinder.bind(name, "name");
add(name);

Button button = new Button("Save", e -> {
    if (personBinder.validate().isOk()) {
      Person p = personBinder.getBean();
      System.out.println(p.getName());
      System.out.println(p.getId());
    }
});
add(button);

Person p = new Person();
p.setName("John");
p.setId("42");

personBinder.setBean(p);
```

As long as there are no validation errors (which is the reason for the check beforehand) the values from the fields are saved in the bean. Of course one has to make sure that the same bean is not somehow modified at some other place.